# angular cli lint error export on a different file

Tags: angular, angular-cli, tslint

I am using [angular cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) for my angular2 project. While I am using [lint](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#linting-and-formatting-code) command for linting-and-formatting-code as follows

```
ng lint
```

I am able to see several errors on my command prompt as follows

```
src/app/quote/your-cart/your-cart.component.ts[118, 9]: missing whitespace
src/app/quote/your-cart/your-cart.component.ts[129, 8]: missing whitespace
src/app/quote/your-cart/your-cart.component.ts[130, 9]: missing whitespace
src/app/quote/your-cart/your-cart.component.ts[142, 21]: missing whitespace
```

Since it is reporting a huge list of errors, I want to export that error on some file. It could be HTML, TXT, or Even JSON is also fine.

**In a nutshell I want to export angular cli lint error to some file.**

Please help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`ng lint` prints to stdout so execute:

```
ng lint > out.txt
```

Works on both *nix and Windows

Answer (score 0):

ng lint | findstr "name.module.ts"
 ng lint | grep "name.module.ts"  in git bash